# Is it OK to call Kafka Streams StreamBuilder.build() multiple times

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, micronaut-kafka

We're using micronaut/kafka-streams. Using this framework in order to create a streams application you build something like this:

```java
@Factory
public class FooTopologyConfig {
  @Singleton
  @Named
  public KStream<String, FooPojo> configureTopology {
    return builder.stream("foo-topic-in")
           .peek((k,v) -> System.out.println(String.format("key %s, value: %s", k,v))
           .to("foo-topic-out");
  }
}
```

This:

- Receives a `ConfiguredStreamBuilder` (a very light wrapper around `StreamsBuilder`)
- Build and return the stream (we're not actually sure how important returning the stream is,
  but that's a different question).

`ConfiguredStreamBuilder::build()` (which invokes the same on `StreamsBuilder`) is called later by the framework and the returned `Topology` is not made available for injection by Micronaut.

We want the `Topology` bean in order to log a description of the topology (via `Topology::describe`).

Is it safe to do the following?

- Call `ConfiguredStreamBuilder::build` (and therefore `StreamsBuilder::build`) and use the returned instance of `Topology` to print a human readable description.
- Allow the framework to call `ConfiguredStreamBuilder::build` for a second time later, and use the *second* instance of the returned topology to build the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem calling `build()` multiple times. This is common in the internal code of Streams as well as in the tests.

To answer your other question. you only need the stream from `builder.stream()` operations if you want to expand on that branch of the topology later.